# Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series

Tags: pine-script

**It was working fine but From yesterday I am Getting this error**
I am using Version 4, I don't know what really happened but from past 3-4 days i am getting this error. I tried **max_bars_back** But it didn't worked. its working in 'M" Time frame only.
I tried to reset settings even i rewrote the code still i ain't able to fix it.
Kindly Help me, I will really Appreciate.

```
//@version=4
strategy("PAIN",overlay=true)
res = input(title="Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval="60",confirm = true)

ProfitPerc = input(title=" Take Profit (%)",type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1.4) * 0.01

stoploss = input(title=" Stop Loss (%)",type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=0.7) * 0.01

CCI = input(10,title = "CCI")
ATR = input(2,title = "ATR")
Multiplier= 1
original = false
thisCCI = cci(close, CCI)
lastCCI = nz(thisCCI[1])


calcx()=> 
    bufferDn= high + Multiplier * wma(tr,ATR)
    bufferUp= low - Multiplier * wma(tr,ATR)
    if (thisCCI >= 0 and lastCCI < 0) 
        bufferUp := bufferDn[1]
    if (thisCCI <= 0 and lastCCI > 0) 
        bufferDn := bufferUp[1]

    if (thisCCI >= 0)
        if (bufferUp < bufferUp[1])
            bufferUp := bufferUp[1]
    else
        if (thisCCI <= 0)
            if (bufferDn > bufferDn[1])
                bufferDn := bufferDn[1]


    x = 0.0
    x := thisCCI >= 0 ?bufferUp:thisCCI <= 0 ?bufferDn:x[1]
    x

tempx = calcx()

calcswap() =>
    swap = 0.0
    swap := tempx>tempx[1]?1:tempx<tempx[1]?-1:swap[1]
    swap

tempswap = calcswap()

swap2=tempswap==1?color.green:color.red
swap3=thisCCI >=0 ?color.green :color.red
swap4=original?swap3:swap2

//display current timeframe's Trend



plot(tempx,color=swap4 == color.green ? color.green : swap4,transp=0,linewidth=4)


htfx = security(syminfo.tickerid,res,tempx[1],lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
htfswap4 = security(syminfo.tickerid,res,swap4[1],lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(htfx,color=htfswap4,transp=0,linewidth=3)

onehour = security(syminfo.tickerid,res,tempx[1],lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
onehour4 = security(syminfo.tickerid,res,swap4[1],lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(onehour,color=onehour4,transp=0,linewidth=2)

//plotarrow( ? 1 : swap4[1] == color.yellow and swap4 == color.blue ? -1 :0 , title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=color.green,colordown = color.blue, maxheight=10, minheight=10, transp=0)

plotshape( swap4[1] == color.red and swap4 == color.green ? 1 : na , style = shape.triangleup , color = color.blue , location = location.belowbar , size = size.tiny )
plotshape( swap4[1] == color.green and swap4 == color.red ? 1 : na , style = shape.triangledown , color = color.red , location = location.abovebar , size = size.tiny)




buy =  swap4[1] == color.red and swap4 == color.green and htfswap4 == color.green

sell =  swap4[1] == color.green and swap4 == color.red and htfswap4 == color.red


if(buy)
    strategy.entry("buy",true)

if(sell)
    strategy.entry("sell",false)

if(swap4[1] == color.red and swap4 == color.green)
    strategy.close("sell")

if(swap4[1] == color.green and swap4 == color.red )
    strategy.close("buy")


longExitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + ProfitPerc)
shortExitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - ProfitPerc)

stop_buy = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stoploss)
stop_sell = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stoploss)


if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="Target", limit=longExitPrice , stop = stop_buy)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="Target", limit=shortExitPrice , stop = stop_sell)


///////////////study("EMA ", overlay=true)
plot(ema(close, 200), color=#FF7000, linewidth=2, title='200 Day EMA')
plot(ema(close, 20), color=#0088FA, linewidth=2, title='20 Day EMA')
plot(ema(close, 50), color=#FA00D0, linewidth=2, title='50 Day EMA')


//////////////////study("Trend Lines+++", overlay=true)
//
src = input(low)
len0 = input(100)

calcSlope(src, len0) =>
    if not barstate.islast
        [float(na), float(na), float(na)]
    else
        sumX = 0.0
        sumY = 0.0
        sumXSqr = 0.0
        sumXY = 0.0
        for i = 0 to len0 - 1
            val = src[i]
            per = i + 1.0
            sumX := sumX + per
            sumY := sumY + val
            sumXSqr := sumXSqr + per * per
            sumXY := sumXY + val * per
        slope = (len0 * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / (len0 * sumXSqr - sumX * sumX)
        average = sumY / len0
        intercept = average - slope * sumX / len0 + slope
        [slope, average, intercept]

[s, a, i] = calcSlope(src, len0)

startPrice = i + s * (len0 - 1)
endPrice = i
var line baseLine = na
if na(baseLine)
    baseLine := line.new(bar_index - len0 + 1, startPrice, bar_index, endPrice, width=4, extend=extend.right)
else
    line.set_xy1(baseLine, bar_index - len0 + 1, startPrice)
    line.set_xy2(baseLine, bar_index, endPrice)
    na 
//

mx = input(100, "Range", minval=1)
mn = max(2, round(mx / 10) + 1)

LN(B, CLR) =>
    s1 = B == 1 ? highest(src, mx) : lowest(src, mx)
    s2 = B == 1 ? highest(src, mn) : lowest(src, mn)
    c1 = s1 == src
    c2 = s2 == src
    b1 = barssince(c1)
    b2 = barssince(c2)
    v1 = valuewhen(c1, s1, 0)
    v2 = valuewhen(c2, s2, 0)
    line.new(bar_index - b1, v1, bar_index - b2, v2, extend=extend.both, color=CLR, width=2)

L1 = LN(1, #ff0088), line.delete(L1[1])
L2 = LN(0, #00ff88), line.delete(L2[1])
//
// Input variables
len=input(30,title="loockback length pivots")
wicks=input(true,title="Draw lines from wicks (checked) or real bodies (unchecked)?")
disp_select=input(true,title="Display only falling 'high' and rising 'low' trendlines?")
do_mono=input(false,title="checked = monochrome lines, unchecked = direction colored lines?")
limit_extension=input(0,title="Limit extensions of the lines? 0 = infinite, other values x 100 bars",minval=0)
do_alerts=input(true,title="show trendline breaks")
trendline_nr=input(5,title="number of past trendlines to check for breaks (max = 10)",minval=0,maxval=10)
select_breaks=input(true,title="only display 'long' breaks on trendlines connecting 'highs' and 'short' for 'lows'")
log_chart=input(false,title="USING A LOG CHART? MAKE SURE TO CHECK THIS BOX!!")


// Calculating the 'time value' of one bar
bar_time=time-time[1]

// Initialising color scheme
var color color_rising=do_mono?color.teal:color.lime
var color color_falling=do_mono?color.teal:color.fuchsia


/////// Function declarations ///////

// Declaration of trendline function
f_trendline(_input_function,_delay,_only_up,_extend) =>
    // Calculate line coordinates (Ax,Ay) - (Bx,By)
    var int Ax = 0
    var int Bx = 0
    var float By = 0.0
    var float slope = 0.0
    Ay = fixnan(_input_function)
    if change(Ay)!=0
        Ax := time[_delay]
        By:= Ay[1]
        Bx := Ax[1]
        slope:=log_chart?((log(Ay)-log(By))/(Ax-Bx)):((Ay-By)/(Ax-Bx))
    else
        Ax := Ax[1]
        Bx := Bx[1]
        By := By[1]
    // Draw trendlines
    var line trendline=na
    var int Axbis=0
    var float Aybis=0.0
    var bool _xtend=true
    extension_time = limit_extension*bar_time*100
    Axbis := Ax + extension_time
    Aybis := log_chart?(Ay*exp(extension_time*slope)):(Ay + extension_time*slope)
    if limit_extension!=0
        _xtend:=false
    if change(Ay)!=0
        line_color = slope*time<0?(_only_up?(disp_select?na:color_rising):color_rising):(_only_up?color_falling:(disp_select?na:color_falling))
        if not na(line_color)
            trendline = line.new(Bx,By,Axbis, Aybis, xloc.bar_time, extend=_xtend?extend.right:extend.none, color=line_color, style=line.style_dotted, width=1)

    [Bx,By,Axbis,Aybis,slope]

// Function to get trendline price for X bars ago ("0" = current value)
line_get_price(_start_time,_start_price,_slope,_lookback_period,_log_chart) =>
    var float current_price=0.0
    elapsed_time = (time-_start_time)
    current_price := _log_chart?(_start_price*exp((elapsed_time-(_lookback_period*bar_time))*_slope)):(_start_price + (elapsed_time-(_lookback_period*bar_time))*_slope)

// Function to check for trendline crosses
line_cross(_check_value,_start_time,_start_price,_slope,_log_chart) =>
    var float current_value=0.0
    var float previous_value=0.0
    // Get current and previous price for the trendline
    current_value := line_get_price(_start_time,_start_price,_slope,0,_log_chart)
    previous_value := line_get_price(_start_time,_start_price,_slope,1,_log_chart)
    // Return 1 for crossover, -1 for crossunder and 0 for no cross detected
    cross =
     _check_value[1]<previous_value and _check_value>current_value?1:
     _check_value[1]>previous_value and _check_value<current_value?-1:0


/////// Start of main script ///////

// Calculate pivot points    
high_point=pivothigh(wicks?high:(close>open?close:open),len,len/2)
low_point=pivotlow(wicks?low:(close>open?open:close),len,len/2)

// Call trendline function for high and low pivot points
[phx1,phy1,phx2,phy2,slope_high]=f_trendline(high_point,len/2,false,true)
[plx1,ply1,plx2,ply2,slope_low]=f_trendline(low_point,len/2,true,true)

// Initialition of pseudo array to keep track of last 10 high and 10 low trendline values
var int high_x0=0, var float high_y0=0.0, var float high_sl0=0.0
var int high_x1=0, var float high_y1=0.0, var float high_sl1=0.0 
var int high_x2=0, var float high_y2=0.0, var float high_sl2=0.0 
var int high_x3=0, var float high_y3=0.0, var float high_sl3=0.0 
var int high_x4=0, var float high_y4=0.0, var float high_sl4=0.0
var int high_x5=0, var float high_y5=0.0, var float high_sl5=0.0
var int high_x6=0, var float high_y6=0.0, var float high_sl6=0.0
var int high_x7=0, var float high_y7=0.0, var float high_sl7=0.0
var int high_x8=0, var float high_y8=0.0, var float high_sl8=0.0
var int high_x9=0, var float high_y9=0.0, var float high_sl9=0.0

var int low_x0=0,  var float low_y0=0.0,  var float low_sl0=0.0
var int low_x1=0,  var float low_y1=0.0,  var float low_sl1=0.0 
var int low_x2=0,  var float low_y2=0.0,  var float low_sl2=0.0 
var int low_x3=0,  var float low_y3=0.0,  var float low_sl3=0.0 
var int low_x4=0,  var float low_y4=0.0,  var float low_sl4=0.0
var int low_x5=0,  var float low_y5=0.0,  var float low_sl5=0.0
var int low_x6=0,  var float low_y6=0.0,  var float low_sl6=0.0
var int low_x7=0,  var float low_y7=0.0,  var float low_sl7=0.0
var int low_x8=0,  var float low_y8=0.0,  var float low_sl8=0.0
var int low_x9=0,  var float low_y9=0.0,  var float low_sl9=0.0

// If a new trendline is formed, shift all values in the array one place up and forget the last values
if change(fixnan(high_point))!=0
    high_x9:=high_x8, high_y9:=high_y8, high_sl9:=high_sl8
    high_x8:=high_x7, high_y8:=high_y7, high_sl8:=high_sl7
    high_x7:=high_x6, high_y7:=high_y6, high_sl7:=high_sl6
    high_x6:=high_x5, high_y6:=high_y5, high_sl6:=high_sl5
    high_x5:=high_x4, high_y5:=high_y4, high_sl5:=high_sl4
    high_x4:=high_x3, high_y4:=high_y3, high_sl4:=high_sl3
    high_x3:=high_x2, high_y3:=high_y2, high_sl3:=high_sl2
    high_x2:=high_x1, high_y2:=high_y1, high_sl2:=high_sl1
    high_x1:=high_x0, high_y1:=high_y0, high_sl1:=high_sl0
    high_x0:=phx1, high_y0:=phy1, high_sl0:=slope_high
if change(fixnan(low_point))!=0
    low_x9:=low_x8, low_y9:=low_y8, low_sl9:=low_sl8
    low_x8:=low_x7, low_y8:=low_y7, low_sl8:=low_sl7
    low_x7:=low_x6, low_y7:=low_y6, low_sl7:=low_sl6
    low_x6:=low_x5, low_y6:=low_y5, low_sl6:=low_sl5
    low_x5:=low_x4, low_y5:=low_y4, low_sl5:=low_sl4
    low_x4:=low_x3, low_y4:=low_y3, low_sl4:=low_sl3
    low_x3:=low_x2, low_y3:=low_y2, low_sl3:=low_sl2
    low_x2:=low_x1, low_y2:=low_y1, low_sl2:=low_sl1
    low_x1:=low_x0, low_y1:=low_y0, low_sl1:=low_sl0
    low_x0:=plx1, low_y0:=ply1, low_sl0:=slope_low

// Check Trendline crosses for last X nr. of trendlines
cross_high0=
 disp_select and high_sl0*time>0?0:
  line_cross(close,high_x0,high_y0,high_sl0,log_chart)
cross_low0=
 disp_select and low_sl0*time<0?0:
  line_cross(close,low_x0,low_y0,low_sl0,log_chart)

cross_high1=
 disp_select and high_sl1*time>0?0:
  line_cross(close,high_x1,high_y1,high_sl1,log_chart)
cross_low1=
 disp_select and low_sl1*time<0?0:
  line_cross(close,low_x1,low_y1,low_sl1,log_chart)

cross_high2=
 disp_select and high_sl2*time>0?0:
  line_cross(close,high_x2,high_y2,high_sl2,log_chart)
cross_low2=
 disp_select and low_sl2*time<0?0:
  line_cross(close,low_x2,low_y2,low_sl2,log_chart)

cross_high3=
 disp_select and high_sl3*time>0?0:
  line_cross(close,high_x3,high_y3,high_sl3,log_chart)
cross_low3=
 disp_select and low_sl3*time<0?0:
  line_cross(close,low_x3,low_y3,low_sl3,log_chart)

cross_high4=
 disp_select and high_sl4*time>0?0:
  line_cross(close,high_x4,high_y4,high_sl4,log_chart)
cross_low4=
 disp_select and low_sl4*time<0?0:
  line_cross(close,low_x4,low_y4,low_sl4,log_chart)

cross_high5=
 disp_select and high_sl5*time>0?0:
  line_cross(close,high_x5,high_y5,high_sl5,log_chart)
cross_low5=
 disp_select and low_sl5*time<0?0:
  line_cross(close,low_x5,low_y5,low_sl5,log_chart)

cross_high6=
 disp_select and high_sl6*time>0?0:
  line_cross(close,high_x6,high_y6,high_sl6,log_chart)
cross_low6=
 disp_select and low_sl6*time<0?0:
  line_cross(close,low_x6,low_y6,low_sl6,log_chart)

cross_high7=
 disp_select and high_sl7*time>0?0:
  line_cross(close,high_x7,high_y7,high_sl7,log_chart)
cross_low7=
 disp_select and low_sl7*time<0?0:
  line_cross(close,low_x7,low_y7,low_sl7,log_chart)

cross_high8=
 disp_select and high_sl8*time>0?0:
  line_cross(close,high_x8,high_y8,high_sl8,log_chart)
cross_low8=
 disp_select and low_sl8*time<0?0:
  line_cross(close,low_x8,low_y8,low_sl8,log_chart)

cross_high9=
 disp_select and high_sl9*time>0?0:
  line_cross(close,high_x9,high_y9,high_sl9,log_chart)
cross_low9=
 disp_select and low_sl9*time<0?0:
  line_cross(close,low_x9,low_y9,low_sl9,log_chart)

long_break=
 (trendline_nr>9?cross_high9==1 or (select_breaks?false:cross_low9==1):false) or
 (trendline_nr>8?cross_high8==1 or (select_breaks?false:cross_low8==1):false) or
 (trendline_nr>7?cross_high7==1 or (select_breaks?false:cross_low7==1):false) or
 (trendline_nr>6?cross_high6==1 or (select_breaks?false:cross_low6==1):false) or
 (trendline_nr>5?cross_high5==1 or (select_breaks?false:cross_low5==1):false) or
 (trendline_nr>4?cross_high4==1 or (select_breaks?false:cross_low4==1):false) or
 (trendline_nr>3?cross_high3==1 or (select_breaks?false:cross_low3==1):false) or
 (trendline_nr>2?cross_high2==1 or (select_breaks?false:cross_low2==1):false) or
 (trendline_nr>1?cross_high1==1 or (select_breaks?false:cross_low1==1):false) or
 cross_high0==1 or (select_breaks?false:cross_low0==1)

short_break=
 (trendline_nr>9?(select_breaks?false:cross_high9==-1) or cross_low9==-1:false) or
 (trendline_nr>8?(select_breaks?false:cross_high8==-1) or cross_low8==-1:false) or
 (trendline_nr>7?(select_breaks?false:cross_high7==-1) or cross_low7==-1:false) or
 (trendline_nr>6?(select_breaks?false:cross_high6==-1) or cross_low6==-1:false) or
 (trendline_nr>5?(select_breaks?false:cross_high5==-1) or cross_low5==-1:false) or
 (trendline_nr>4?(select_breaks?false:cross_high4==-1) or cross_low4==-1:false) or
 (trendline_nr>3?(select_breaks?false:cross_high3==-1) or cross_low3==-1:false) or
 (trendline_nr>2?(select_breaks?false:cross_high2==-1) or cross_low2==-1:false) or
 (trendline_nr>1?(select_breaks?false:cross_high1==-1) or cross_low1==-1:false) or
 (select_breaks?false:cross_high0==-1) or cross_low0==-1

// Plot and connect pivot points
color_high=slope_high*time<0?color_rising:(disp_select?na:color_falling)
color_low=slope_low*time>0?color_falling:(disp_select?na:color_rising)
plot(high_point,color=color_high,offset=-len/2)
plot(low_point,color=color_low,offset=-len/2)
//
// Function outputs 1 when it's the first bar of the D/W/M/Y
is_newbar(res) =>
    ch = 0
    if(res == 'Y')
        t  = year(time('D'))
        ch := change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
    else
        t = time(res)
        ch := change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
    ch

////////////
// INPUTS //
////////////

pp_period = input(title = "Period", type=input.string, defval="Day", options = ['Day', 'Week', 'Month', 'Year'])

pp_res = pp_period == 'Day' ? 'D' : pp_period == 'Week' ? 'W' : pp_period == 'Month' ? 'M' : 'Y' 

/////////////////////
// Get HLC from HT //

// Calc High
high_cur = 0.0
high_cur := is_newbar(pp_res) ? high : max(high_cur[1], high)

phigh = 0.0
phigh := is_newbar(pp_res) ? high_cur[1] : phigh[1]

// Calc Low
low_cur = 0.0
low_cur := is_newbar(pp_res) ? low : min(low_cur[1], low)

plow = 0.0
plow := is_newbar(pp_res) ? low_cur[1] : plow[1]

// Calc Close
pclose = 0.0
pclose := is_newbar(pp_res) ? close[1] : pclose[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A recent deployment is causing the problem. Use:

```
strategy("PAIN",overlay=true, max_bars_back=300)
```

The Pine team is looking into it. Sorry for the inconvenience.